# How to back up encrypted /data atomically in Android 12?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, encryption, disk-encryption

I accidentally upgraded my phone to Android 12 instead of a newer Android 11 and, to my dismay, it seems encryption was changed in a way that makes TWRP unable to decrypt my /data.

For backups, I ran [borgbackup](https://www.borgbackup.org/) on /data from TWRP and would like to continue doing so. This strategy relied on TWRP being able to decrypt /data however.

Is there another way to get:

- Decrypted /data
- No active processes modifying /data (ideally have it readonly)
- Shell access
- A writable rootfs where I can create a subdirectory to mount a tmpfs on

I tried using Magisk to `mount -o remount,ro /data` in a running system but that didn't work: `mount: '/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata'->'/data': Device or resource busy`

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=balti.migrate

Comment: Is that an answer? If so, post it as one. Also, does that even fit in here? Is its backup mechanism atomic?

Comment: TWRP does not support Samsung encryption, just left a link for alternative backup method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 3.7.0, [TWRP now supports Android 12's decryption](https://twrp.me/site/update/2022/10/10/3.7.0-released.html), so that fixes that.

Should something like this happen again in the future, [Shut down the Android OS partially into a "recovery mode"/recovery runlevel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246841/shut-down-the-android-os-partially-into-a-recovery-mode-recovery-runlevel/) could also be used to back up data without any process writing but I haven't tried to make that work with my special setup yet.