# Shut down the Android OS partially into a "recovery mode"/recovery runlevel

Tags: recovery-mode, services

Android fundamentally still is a Linux system which have runlevels/targets intended for recovery purposes.

Is it possible to stop the Android OS far enough so that Apps, the UI and most system services aren't running anymore but I still have adb access?

Comment: This is a possible solution to https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246840/how-to-back-up-encrypted-data-atomically-in-android-12 but I feel it's worth its own question.

Comment: Android uses Linux kernel but userspace is entirely different than common Linux distros. There are no `init` runlevels or targets. Recovery is a complete operating system in itself, having its own kernel and `init`. Related: [How to quickly understand the Android UI](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221825/218526). `adbd` is an `init` service which can run independent of the UI. But it can be tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a related discussion, [a Reddit user pointed out to me](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/103n5ef/do_new_addons_require_to_format_my_phone_after_an/j342wt3/) that the `stop` and `start` commands offer a functionality like this.

`stop` brings most of the Android system down, including apps, services etc. but not ADB.

`start` starts the Android system again from the boot animation.