# Manually decrypt data from recovery-mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, encryption, disk-encryption

AFAICT, Android builds upon Linux' standard fscrypt as implemented in ext4 and f2fs.

I know my pattern and have access to a shell with any Linux program in it.

How can I decrypt /data manually, without the Android OS running? (i.e. from Lineage Recovery)
If that's not feasible, why?

Comment: This is a possible solution to https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246840/how-to-back-up-encrypted-data-atomically-in-android-12 but I feel it's worth its own question.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/3894561